# UIImageView clipping just some subviews

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, uibutton, subview

I have an UIImageView with content mode Aspect Fill and it's clipping its subviews.
Now I want to add a button as subview and it should protrude at the edges about 20px.

The problem is that the option "clip subview" in interface builder cuts the subviews (as expected).

Is there a possibility to get what I want? Any ideas? Thanks, with kind regards, Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this as I did. I found my solution to be setting `clipsToBounds` on the image view to FALSE:

```
[_myImageView addSubview:_myButton];
_myImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Now my button overlaps the edges of the image view.

Answer (score 0):

Add the UIButton to the UIImageView's superview and it won't be clipped.